# magento skip payment method from checkout

Tags: magento, checkout, enterprise, payment-method

I have magento EE 1.14.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now.
How can I skip payment method from checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

Any suggestion welcome in advanced.

Comment: you cannot place an order until payment is not done. you can enable Cash on delivery/Check money order on temporary basis and disable others

Comment: yes @Manashvibirla I have enable "Check money" option but is there any way to hide that step & programmatically set default payment method and shift to review step?

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/

Comment: Not sure but you can use the onepage checkout and hide the payment block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below link to hide payment method.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/

Please let me know if you need any help from my side.

Comment: Thanks @Bharat I already did this & it works, but my problem is what I use instead of **payment[method]=free**. I have one method only check / money. Please do suggest.